# What does the medallion next to a message signify?

Tags: dark-souls-3

In *Dark Souls 3* (and some of the previous games in the series, if I remember correctly), messages on the ground have a "medallion" to the left of the message text, as pictured below:

[image]

The majority of messages I see in-game have the style of medallion shown in the picture above, but I have seen a few that are gold or blue, and have different designs on them. I know the "bell" design signifies that the message is a "system" message (i.e. a message that was hard-coded into the game), but I'm not sure about any of the others.

Does anyone know what the different medallion colors/designs mean? My google-fu is normally pretty strong, but it has failed me when it comes to answering this question.

Comment: A quick Google pointed me to [a wiki excerpt](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Messages) that detailed the symbol as representing the amount of upvotes the message has received, however; there was nothing about colour, or the particular symbol in your question. I would recommend cropping the image down to just the symbol, and running a reverse Google image search.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's related to the number of ratings the message has received. The higher the number of ratings, a different medallion picture displays.

Comment: Thank you for confirming what @Timelord64 suspected! I would appreciate it if someone could update this answer with the rating ranges and associated "medallions" whenever the community discovers what those are.